# MapView inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager with some pages: one of those is a WebView ('case 0' in the code below). The problem is that instead visualizing the map, a blank page is displayed. What's wrong in my implemetation?

edit: cleared the code

my code

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    Context context = container.getContext();
    prepareViews();

    m_mapView = new MapView(context, null);
    m_mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    m_mapView.setMultiTouchControls(false);
    mapController = this.m_mapView.getController();



    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        layout.addView(m_mapView);

       break;
    case 1:
        ...
       break;
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
    }
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0); 
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial for ViewPager's, it has layouts being inflated.

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    resId = profileLayouts[position];
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
```

In your case, you would do this with the layout variable. Once it is inflated, you can manipulate it, add the map, and then add the view.

```
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0); 
    return view;
```